# Current mode buck regulator design

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I've got a project at my university that includes a peltier module for heating and cooling stuff. A big problem I'm encountering is that the peltier module sucks 5A at 12V, but the biggest power supply allowed is 12V 3A, so I've got to limit the current through the module. At first I thought of a big-ass 12ohm resistor but that is not really practical, and a 12W resistor is both hard to find and kindof expensive. So is a buck regulator the solution to this problem? I've come up with this design for the regulator:
[image]

The ATTiny45 is supposed to increase or decrease the pulse width going to the switching mosfet until the sensed current is around 1A, in this case until ADC_IN is about 1 volt.
If this principle would work, let's say there will be a resistor divider to sense the voltage for the output of the buck regulator to control the pulse width based on the delivered power instead of only the current (which seems to be a better idea now that I think of it), how do I calculate the best frequency to drive the switching transistor at? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current sense will be an RL charge/discharge waveform, and the fastest loop frequency for your regulation is going to be limited by the fastest rate of A/D conversions for your MCU. 
Since you have no output capacitance, your current detector is measuring the peak current (and only then after an ADC delay). The rate of current rise through your inductor you should be well equipped to calculate (hint, the inductor is too low a value for what can be achieved inside a MCU loop)

I'd suggest that you also need a capacitor from Pin 1 of your connector to ground which will reduce the peaky waveform you currently have and help you more reasonably control the current.

Comment: Thanks very much for the feedback, I really appreciate it. I'll shove a 470uF low ESR cap between pin1 and gnd and see how it performs, right now I've built the circuit with a 220uH inductor and the inductor and the switching transistor are getting quite hot at 10W output (didn't let the magic smoke out yet but it's boiling alright). I hope the cap will improve things a bit.

Comment: @AndreiDragan. 220 uH sounds better. Your P-Channel FET should not get hot, it should off or saturated.

Comment: is the formula Ipeak = V * Ton / L by any chance the one for calculating the rate of current rise through the inductor? If it is, I think I can work with much lower values like 22uH since the uC can output PWM at 250KHz and the ADC can sample at about 125ksps. Of course, this means I'll probably need a mosfet driver to drive the PMOS to avoid it being in its resistive state, but other than that is there another flaw in this idea? 220uH is kindof chunky and I could have better use for the saved PCB space.